# Using datacontext to call method from another window

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

i have an app that use two separate windows, i need to call from Window2 a method in Window1. Window1 has a frame that load different classes. When a specific class will be loaded i need to run a method in this class from Window2 (so the method that i have to run isn't in MainWindow class but in a class that the MainWindow frame load..),using this code in Window2 i can see the method that i wanna call:

```
Application curApp = Application.Current;
var mainWnd = curApp.MainWindow as MainWindow;   
var myClass = mainWnd.DataContext as Page2Class;
myClass.MyMethod();
```

AnyWay "myClass" is null and myClass.MyMethod() crash... How i can do? There's another way to resolve my problem?

Comment: Where do you set the `DataContext`? Right now, it's absolutely normal that it's null.

Comment: It seems that mainWnd.DataContext is not a Page2Class, what is this DataContext?

Comment: can you show me how i can assign the mainWindow datacontext to Page2Class?

Answer (score 0):

Well, i think this corresponds to ViewModels interaction. The best approach you can use is to implement mediator to couple your VM's.

Here is a paper to read: [VM's Interaction](http://joyfulwpf.blogspot.nl/2009/05/mvvm-communication-among-viewmodels.html)

In one of my projects i had a very similar question and implemented it with events, it was bad and i don't like this approach, because it's hard to set up and hard to test and maintain, so i highly reccomend you to understand and implement some kind of mediator

Comment: thank you ,i'll read about mediator that i don't know until now but for my issues i have solved in another way.

Answer (score 0):

Solved in this way:

```
Application curApp = Application.Current;
var mainWnd = curApp.MainWindow as MainWindow;   
var content = mainWnd._mainFrame.Content as SlotMachine;
 content.MyMethod();
```